# How to open a window and close another window when a button is pressed with javascript?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

I am in quite a bind right now! You will notice in the Demo provided below that when you click the black button a window appears with another button in it. What I am trying to achieve is when you click the light gray button it will shut that whole window from the black button and open a whole new window! Below I will have some code and a demo!

HTML

```
<div id="sidemenu">
<div id="regionsContainer">
    <div id="regionsUnitedStates" class="not-open regionsButton">
    <div id="regionsUnitedStatesTooltip"></div>
    </div>
    <div id="regionsCanada" class="not-open regionsButton">
     <div id="regionsCanadaTooltip"></div>
    </div>
</div>
<div id="regionsUnitedStatesChooseState" class="regionsContent">
    <div id="chooseStateUnitedStatesColumnOne">
            <div id="chooseStateAlabama"></div>
    </div>
</div>
<div id="regionsCanadaChooseProvince" class="regionsContent">CDN</div>
```

CSS

```
#sidemenu {
    width: 60px;
    max-height: 100%;
    min-height: 100%;
    min-width: 60px;
    max-width: 60px;
    background-color: #383D3F;
    background-size: 100% 100%;
    background-attachment: fixed;
    position: absolute;
    left: -60px;
    transition: left ease-in-out 0.5s;
    top: 0;
}
#sidemenu.show {
    left: 0;
}
#regionsContainer {
    width: 60px;
    height: 100%;
    min-height: 100%;
    min-width: 60px;
    max-width: 60px;
    max-height: 100%;
    background-color: #383D3F;
    position: absolute;
    top:25%;
}
#regionsUnitedStates {
    width: 60px;
    height: 60px;
    background-color:#111111;
}
#regionsUnitedStatesTooltip {
    opacity:0;
    background-color:#000;
    height:60px;
    width:180px;
    left:100px;
    position:absolute;
    transition:all ease-in-out 0.25s;
    top:0;
    visibility:hidden;
}
#regionsUnitedStates.not-open:hover #regionsUnitedStatesTooltip{
    left: 60px;
    opacity:1;
    visibility:visible;
    }
#regionsUnitedStates:hover {
    background-position:bottom;
}
#regionsUnitedStatesChooseState{
    position:absolute;
    transition:all ease-in-out 0.25s;
    left: -500px;
    width: 500px;
    height: 100%;
    background: #505759;
    top:0;
    z-index:-1;
}
#regionsUnitedStatesChooseState.show {
    left: 60px;
    z-index:-1;
}
#regionsCanada {
    width: 60px;
    height: 60px;
    background-color:#666;
}
#regionsCanadaTooltip {
    opacity:0;
    background-color:#000000;
    height:60px;
    width:120px;
    left:100px;
    position:absolute;
    transition:all ease-in-out 0.25s;
    top:60px;
    visibility:hidden;
}
#regionsCanada.not-open:hover #regionsCanadaTooltip{
    left: 60px;
    opacity:1;
    visibility:visible;
    }
#regionsCanada:hover {
    background-position:bottom;
}
#regionsCanadaChooseProvince{
    position:absolute;
    transition:all ease-in-out 0.25s;
    left: -500px;
    width: 500px;
    height: 100%;
    background: #505759;
    top:0;
    z-index:-1;
}
#regionsCanadaChooseProvince.show {
    left: 60px;
    z-index:-1;
}
#chooseStateUnitedStatesColumnOne {
    width:150px;
    height:540px;
    float:left;     
}
#chooseStateAlabama {
    width: 150px;
    height:54px;
    background-color:#999999;
    top:0px;
}
#chooseStateAlabama:hover {
    background-color:#999888;   
    cursor:pointer;
}
```

Javascript

```
$(function(slideSidemenu) {
    setTimeout(function() { $("#sidemenu").addClass("show") }, 500);
});

var $regionsContent = $('.regionsContent'), 
$regionsButton = $('.regionsButton').click(function(){
    var $button = $(this).removeClass('not-open');
    var buttonIndex = $regionsButton.index($button);
    $regionsContent.removeClass('show').eq(buttonIndex).addClass('show');
    $regionsButton.not($button).addClass('not-open');
});
```

DEMO

[JSFIDDLE DEMO](http://jsfiddle.net/4Lbhk/6/)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Is this what you are looking for? http://jsfiddle.net/4Lbhk/4/

I added a timeout before showing the other page:

```
setTimeout(function() {

    $regionsContent.eq(buttonIndex).addClass('show');
}, 300);
```

Comment: Not what I was looking for but I see where you got confused! I updated the demo to make it more clear! This is a cool effect that I will use though :)

Comment: Still not sure I get it 100% but is this closer to what you are looking for? http://jsfiddle.net/4Lbhk/7/

Comment: Yes But i dont want to open the canada window I want to open a different window. Do i just change the div in the timeout function?

Comment: Exactly right. Just give it a different ID and use that ID

Comment: Thank you! I just used that and made a new div and it is exactly what I wanted! Thank you so much man! I'm still a newb at javascript! :(

Answer (score 0):

I am not sure of your question, but if you want to close the window from within the inside grey div, you could do:

```
$("#chooseStateAlabama").click(function(){
    $('.regionsContent').removeClass('show');
});
```

If you want to open another page in the whole page, something like this?

```
$("#chooseStateAlabama").click(function(){
    window.open("http://stackoverflow.com/","_self","");
});
```

Comment: The top part is what i'm looking for as far as hiding but I would also like to open a new window once the .regionContent is hidden